# Android studio fail to install app on device

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, build, ioexception

I have a **Samsung Galaxy S5** device running **Android 4.4.2**
it was working just fine until a few weeks a go I started getting this issue, Android Studio fail to install the app after I press run and build the gradle

**Additional information :** I tried to run the app on an emulatir the first time it work and after I did some changes I tried to run on the emulator again but the changes were noy applied

**This is the gradle file :**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.incorp.anisvikernes.appex"
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 19
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.1.0'
}
```

**This is the LogCat :**

```
03:49:45 Executing tasks: [clean, :app:generateDebugSources,       :app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources, :app:prepareDebugUnitTestDependencies, :app:mockableAndroidJar, :app:compileDebugSources, :app:compileDebugAndroidTestSources, :app:compileDebugUnitTestSources]
03:51:04 Gradle build finished in 1m 18s 412ms
05:23:54 Executing tasks: [:app:assembleDebug]
05:28:19 Gradle build finished in 4m 25s 153ms
05:28:32 Error during Sync: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
05:28:32 Session 'app': Error Installing APK
```

**This is the error**

```
08/20 05:28:26: Launching app
$ adb push D:\projects\appex\app\build\outputs\apk\app-debug.apk   /data/local/tmp/com.incorp.anisvikernes.appex
java.io.IOException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
Error while Installing APK
```

Comment: Rebuild, Clean & Rerun

Comment: invalidate cache restart.

Comment: VVB that is not a permanent solution and it doesn't work all the time, @Sohail Zahid how do I exactly do that please ??

Comment: its below the project settings.

Comment: @SohailZahid unfortunately invalidating cache didn't solve my problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually found a solution that fixed this problem, it will seem really odd and wierd but after **updating my driver** (Win key+x -> device manager -> going to my device and pressing update button) I **changed the USB cable** used to connect the phone to my PC and it worked immediately

Answer (score 0):

I solved the same issue by

```
1. Disable USB debugging and developer options
2. Disconnect the device from USB 
3. Re enable USB debugging and developer options
4. Reconnect device
```

Some said at the time I had the problem killing and restarting the adb worked.

Comment: That didn't work and I tried killing the adb from te task manager and terminal but I still have the same problem

Answer (score -1):

After hours of no success, removing the USB-Extension cable worked for me. 
Anything worked with the usb-extension cable except the Installing APK process as you described. Maybe others can fix it to by changing the USB-cable to a short, stable working cable.