# Apk not Installed on Android

Tags: android, apk

How to fix ‘Application not Installed’ error on Androids

Comment: Sorry, what was your question?

Comment: @MalikAbuQaoud Sorry Whats your question??Details aren't sufficient..

Comment: I have encountered this problem and i found a solution

Comment: CHECK THIS [Android studio fail to install app on device](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39050538/android-studio-fail-to-install-app-on-device)

Answer (score 0):

The Android SDK Manager provides the SDK tools, platforms, and other components you need to develop your apps.

To open the SDK Manager, click Tools > Android > SDK Manager or click SDK Manager  in the toolbar.

When an update is available for a package you already have, a dash  appears in the check box next to the package.

To update an item or install a new one, click the check box so it shows a checkmark.
To uninstall a package, click to clear the check box.
Pending updates are indicated in the left column with a download icon . Pending removals are indicated with a red cross .

To update the selected packages, click Apply or OK, then agree to any license agreements.

Answer (score 0):

refer this links

['App not Installed' Error on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4226132/app-not-installed-error-on-android)

and this one

http://mobilityarena.com/fix-application-not-installed-error-androids/